# Android show information in a specific day on calendar

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

Not a problem per se but I am figuring out how to do something. In my app, I shall save some workout for every specific client. Any workout will be doing different from week to week; i.e: rep scheme in the week one shall be different from the week two, and so on.

So, how to show the user that in the calendar? Should I save in every workout the day it should be performed and then see if it's the same day and show it? Or how to implement this? The only way I thought to implement this is save in every workout the day that it should be performed and show it in a textview and all the info behind relationated with the workout without calendar use but don't know if this approach would be the best

I have searched on the web but found nothing. If you could give me a hint would be awesome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider

Comment: https://developers.google.com/calendar/

Comment: How did you search? There are lot of android developer guides..